# A proper way to update the state in the parent through buttons in childs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of the parent bypassing the handler function to the child but I am getting an error:

```
class Parent(){
  contractor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answer: ""
    }
  };

  hanadleAnswer = _answer => {
    this.setState({ answer: _answer });
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <Switch>
         <Route path="questions" component={<Child handler={_answer => this.handleAnswer(_answer)}/>}
       </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

In the child, I wanted to update the state of the answer according to the sent answer of option

```
function Child({ handler }){
  ... 
  <Button onClick={handler({option_1})}></Button> 
  <Button onClick={handler({option_2})}></Button> 
  ...
}
```

I realized that the handler is fired even without clicking on the button, with an error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

If this method doesn't work, how can I update the state of the parent according to the value coming from child bu buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this-

```
function Child({ handler }){
  ... 
  <Button onClick={()=>handler({option_1})}></Button> 
  <Button onClick={()=>handler({option_2})}></Button> 
  ...
}
```

Reference for better understanding [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
. Quoting from that page:

> ### Passing Arguments to Event Handlers
>
> Inside a loop, it is common to want to pass an extra parameter to an event handler. For example, if id is the row ID, either of the following would work:
>
> ```
> <button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
> <button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
> ```

Comment: Thank you a lot :) it's working! Can you explain why this worked? What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @White159 you can check concept and reference posted... please accept/vote for this if answer is helpful for you.